# How do I make my Discord Bot reply a same answer to different words from a list? Python

Tags: python, discord

I want my discord bot to reply with "Hey" to any word in "greetings" and answer "goodbye" to any word in "farewell"

I tried this code but it marks a SyntaxError in "elif".

```
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

Greeting = ['hi', 'hello']
farewell = ['bye', 'goodbye']

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

for word in Greeting:
 elif word in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('hey')

for word in farewell:
 elif word in message.content:
   await message.channel.send('goodbye')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I then tried to make them separated events like this

```
Greeting = ['hi', 'hello']
farewell = ['bye', 'goodbye']

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    for word in Greeting:
     if word in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('hey')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    for word in farewell:
     if word in message.content:
       await message.channel.send('goodbye')
```

But then it would only answer to "farewell" and not to "greetings"

Comment: elif must be part of an if statement, not a standalone https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#elif

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused. You only use `elif` after an if statement, not `for`, so replacing `elif` by `if` should work. You can kind of see that in your second solution which almost does what you want, but because you have defined a function with the same name twice, the first one is "hidden".

```
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()
Greeting = ['hi', 'hello']
farewell = ['bye', 'goodbye']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    for word in Greeting:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('hey')

    for word in farewell:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('goodbye')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: I tried this and it says that "await" is outside of a function

"SyntaxError: 'await' outside function"

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was an absolutely horrible copy pasta job on my part. Fixed it and should work now.